# Posting T with RestSharp to MVC4 api server gives null object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, restsharp, restful-architecture

I have this common CUser class

```
public class CUser
{
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this code on my client that uses RestSharp

```
    public void CreateUser()
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.Resource = "user/{cUser}";

        CUser user = new CUser
        {
            Username = "Foo",
            Password = "BarBaz"
        };

        request.AddParameter("cUser", user, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        client.PostAsync<int>(request, (response, handler) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id: " + response.Data);
            });
    }
```

And this http route in my global.asax

```
            routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CreateUser",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{cUser}",
            defaults: new
                          {
                              controller = "User",
                              action = "CreateUser",
                              cUser = RouteParameter.Optional
                          });
```

And this servercode to handle it

```
    public int CreateUser(CUser cUser)
    {
        User user = new User(cUser);
        LoginManager manager = new LoginManager();
        return manager.CreateUser(user);
    }
```

But everytime I run it cUser's values are null (Username and Password) so do I need to do something to restsharp to make it serialize it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
request.AddParameter("username", user.Username);
request.AddParameter("password", user.Password);
```

What you're doing would result in `cUser.ToString()` being substituted for the `{cUser}` placeholder.

Comment: Still gets null in both parameters on the server when I change it to http://pastebin.com/AfsJhJyL if I change the website to CreateUser(string Username, string Password) it works fine, but its so much easier if I can send Objects

Comment: You can't send objects in the URL. It's just not a thing HTTP supports. You could use AddBody() to send it as JSON in the request body.

Comment: I dont want to send the object itself, but I would like RestSharp and the modelbinder to fix all that jazz for me so I just provide an object in one end and pull out that object in the other end, would that then be the addbody?